# Build SOAP header

Tags: php, xml, web-services, soap

i need use a SOAP webservice for a project.

The webservice requires authentication via a SOAP header like this:

```
<soap:Header>
    <wsse:Security soap:mustUnderstand="true" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
        <wsse:UsernameToken>
            <wsse:Username>STAGING_WS</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">ANDREANI</wsse:Password>
        </wsse:UsernameToken>
    </wsse:Security>
</soap:Header>
```

So, i tried build the headers using SoapHeader class as below:

```
$ns = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd";

$auth = new \StdClass();
$auth->Username = new \SoapVar('STAGING_WS', XSD_STRING, NULL, $ns, NULL, $ns);
$auth->Password = new \SoapVar('ANDREANI', XSD_STRING, NULL, $ns, NULL, $ns);

$token = new \StdClass();
$token->UsernameToken = new \SoapVar($auth, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, NULL, $ns, 'UsernameToken', $ns);
$security = new \SoapVar(new \SoapVar($token, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, NULL, $ns, 'UsernameToken', $ns), SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, NULL, $ns, 'Security', $ns);

$header = new \SoapHeader('wsse', 'Security', $security, true);
```

But, the generatd header is not equal:

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:ns1="http://www.andreani.com.ar" xmlns:ns2="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:ns3="wsse">
<env:Header>
<ns3:Security env:mustUnderstand="true">
<ns2:UsernameToken>
<ns2:Username>STAGING_WS</ns2:Username>
<ns2:Password>ANDREANI</ns2:Password>
</ns2:UsernameToken>
</ns3:Security>
</env:Header>
<env:Body>
<ns1:ConfirmarCompra/>
</env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the last line to:

```
$header = new \SoapHeader($ns, 'Security', $security, true);
```

This will make the namespace of the `Security` tag to be the same as `UsernameToken`, `Username` and `Password` tags. The local name for the security namespace will be still `ns2` and not `wsse` but that doesn't really matter. The correct SOAP Server must accept it as long as the namespace url is correct.